# Error while mounting root in node of a cluster

Tags: virtualbox, dns, nfs, virtualbox-networking, cluster

I was trying to make a cluster on VirtualBox, wherein while performing the mounting part, I was getting this error

mount.nfs: failed to resolve server master. Name or service not found.

My commands were as follows :

mount master:/root /root

mount master:/export /export

Comment: Why are you mounting `master`, not an IP address?

Comment: I wanted to form a cluster for distributed data mining. I'm following this video for the process. https://youtu.be/9MSQxGhT3M0

Comment: If you have any other way to do it, please help me out.

Comment: The problem is that `master` is a unknown name in your namelookup service. Either use the IP address as Mark Yisri already suggested or configure your namelookup services ( DNS / `/etc/hosts` on each node ).

Comment: So, I should be writing the ip address of the master node in the command instead of '' master ''

Comment: @Arushi That's correct.